# How powerful could lasers be at various sizes if the power source issue is solved?

Tags: science-based, warfare, near-future, lasers

How powerful and how long a range could lasers get with no power source issue at
the sizes of:

- ~5-7 kilograms, man portable
- ~20 kilograms, semi man portable like
  the PTRS
- ~300 kilograms, wheeled carriage mounted, no motor
- ~1250 kilograms, tank mounted
- ~the size of a 175mm cannon

The power source is hyper-advanced but in terms of everything else its only what we have now and what is currently in development. How powerful could lasers of & how long a range would they have under these conditions?

Comment: While I expect some answers will be given, if you think about it, this an impossible question to answer. How can we predict the development of new lasing technologies? Light emitters? Optics? Computer controls? This kind of question fits into my category of, "How many angels can dance on the head of a pin? Answer: As many as wanting." It's your world, you can have the lasers as powerful as they need to be. Therefore, what rule of your world needs defining to make what you need to have happen, happen? Said another way, why are you asking this question?

Comment: Also, please note that you're asking, from a practical standpoint, 5 * 2 = 10 questions on a service that permits only one.

Comment: What do you mean by the "range" of a laser? Range of doing what, and under what conditions? Is the "power" impulse power or average power over a period of time?

Comment: Where does the assumption come from that currently the power source is the issue? Also what AlexP says. In vacuum the range of a laser can be infinite. In earth's atmosphere it varies as much on the laser (and wavelength) as on the atmosphere.

Comment: This seems more an engineering question than worldbuilding.

Comment: As a point of comparison, I have one of [these Jenoptik laser modules](https://www.jenoptik.com/products/lasers/high-power-diode-lasers/selector/vertical-cw-stacks), they're not much bigger than matchboxes, I kid you not, the cooling water hose fittings are bigger than the whole laser! Just add cold water, power and a lens and you'll be able to cut through car doors (albeit no faster than a demolition saw, but still). A unit the size of a microwave would melt though tank armor in a couple seconds (bonus: if you focus the beam to a couple megawatts/cm2 you ***plasmise the atmosphere***)

Answer (score 4):

#### Your limited by waste heat. Few good shots and then they overheat.

If your limit is current tech minus all power supply issues, your next limit will be the efficiency of the semiconductors.

Quoting from a Wikipedia page on using lasers to [transmit power long distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerlight_Technologies), you're looking at about an 85% ceiling on the efficiency of laser emitters at turning input power into photons at current or near future tech. The other 15% heats up the gun.

A 10kw power supply fires 8.5kw of laser and also functions as a 1.5kw heater heating up the gun and the guy holding it.

So - how hot can your laser rifle get before it melts, burns you, or (if it has a fan) it heats the room up enough that you pass out from heatstroke?

Lets assume your guns are made of steel. Steel melts at ~1500 degrees C. If you're firing from a 20 degree room, (and have epic gloves), your gun can take ~5MJ of waste heat before melting - giving a limit of 33MJ for your rifle before it melts. You probably want to stop well before this point though - malleable guns don't shoot straight.

33MJ is enough to melt 5 x 7kg laser guns into a puddle, so it can do some damage if concentrated into pulses and hits the bad guys just right. Probably flash boil a chunk of whoever it hits, or at least melt their armour or uniform into their skin.

However it's not a super weapon. 33MJ (33 MW applied for 1 second) is powerful,  but not insane.
The [death star laser was 2.4×10^32 watts](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Superlaser/Legends#:%7E:text=The%20power%20of%20the%20first,ever%20built%20at%20the%20time.) and a [ship mounted laser in Star Wars is 5GJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blaster_(Star_Wars)).

However after you've fired enough rounds that the gun is getting close to overheating - you have to wait. Even with a large cooling fan it's going to take several minutes to bring the gun back down to operating temperature again.

A cooling system needs somewhere to dump the heat, so a backpack mounted radiator might buy a few more shots, but then they're melting their buddy behind them. You can't "toss it in water" or something either - cooling these intricate parts down unevenly would warp the weapon.

Same with the bigger designs. A tank-mounted laser cannon could disable several enemy tanks, but they then need to retreat for an hour to get the waste heat out. A platoon of tanks would be limited by heating up the surrounding air and ground, a tank in the middle of a tight formation could conceivably overheat without firing a shot just from the surrounding waste heat.

A laser equiped forces weakness would be ir imaging and heat sinking missiles. A smart enemy would send bait targets into enemy territory, they'd activate lasers to shoot, theyd heat up, and then the enemy would wipe the hot lasers (or radiators) out with heat seaking missiles

You also asked about range - basically a laser travels as far as you can see - Itll be affected by atmospheric but on a clear day or in a vacuum you'll be limited by how accurately you can point them at the bad guys.

Comment: The effective range of the laser is determined by the tightness of the beam, which in turn depends on the optics.  If the beam spreads out before reaching the target, effectiveness is greatly reduced, particularly for lower wattage man-portable weapons.